# ERROR: syntax error at or near "TO"

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql, terminal

I'm getting a syntax error when trying to define a new user for my rails data base in the postgresql environment.

```
postgres=# GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON simple_cms_db.* TO 'rails_user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'secretpassword';

ERROR:  syntax error at or near "TO"
```

This is just an out of the box rails app created with `rails new appname -d postgresql`. All I've done so far to the the app is create two data bases: `simple_cms_db` and `simple_cms_db_test`

Rails 5.1.6

Ruby 2.4.1p111

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is create an user `CREATE USER rails_user WITH PASSWORD 'my_password';`. Once we have that you can rewrite the privilege command like the below ones

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE simple_cms_db TO rails_user;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE simple_cms_db_test TO rails_user;
```

Comment: Thanks, but when I did that I got 
**ERROR:  syntax error at or near "."**

Comment: The new one you posted gives me **ERROR:  syntax error at or near "'rails_user'"**

Comment: Updated the answer. Probably the syntax you're trying works with MySQL, however the same syntax I have not tried in Postgres. Hence, I'm splitting them into CREATE and then GRANT

Comment: ok it looks like splitting it up worked. The tutorial I'm watching uses MySql but I'm using postgres so maybe you are right. But I'm confused, I thought all syntax is the same for both MySQL and Postgres because the langauge is SQL for both. Why would the syntax differ?

Comment: Although they use SQL for both, I think there is a difference at the query level, and internally they both should be doing the same-thing. I maybe wrong with this, this is how I have understood it, I'll continue to look into this.